# CSS transition [background-image property] works only in chrome

Tags: css, css-transitions

I published a website at: http://semep.com.br

The background photo is modified for each banner on this page.
I would like to place a transition effect in the photo as a background fade:

### CSS Rule

```
#fullbackground{

    /* Set rules to fill background */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    transition: background-image 800ms ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: background-image 800ms ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: background-image 800ms ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: background-image 800ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 800ms ease-in-out; 
}
```

### Script to change background image

```
  window.modificarBackground = function(bgArquivo) {
    if (screen.width > 1280) {
      bgArquivo = "url('/Images/Fundo/1600/" + bgArquivo + "')";
    }
    if (screen.width <= 1024) {
      bgArquivo = "url('/Images/Fundo/1024/" + bgArquivo + "')";
    }
    if (screen.width > 1024 && screen.width <= 1280) {
      bgArquivo = "url('/Images/Fundo/1280/" + bgArquivo + "')";
    }
    return $("#fullbackground").css("background-image", bgArquivo);
  };
```

In chrome works perfectly!

**In other browsers for this effect is just a blank screen!**

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to use CSS but what about using jQuery? I recently wanted to do something much like this.  I used the functions fadeIn and fadeOut. These may be of some help to you.

These links may be helpful:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: I would try to use a CSS solution first.
If not, i try a solution with jquery!

Comment: background image transition is not supported in current browsers... you could just cross fade two overlaid images(no need for jquery there with css transitioning the opacity)